# Why does getattr not act the same as manually newing up object

Tags: python, python-module, getattr, repr

Can someone please explain why I get different output when I run the Python script below?

I don't understand why `getattr(sys.modules['importme'], 'MyClass')` does not print the custom `__repr__()` function defined in `MyClass`.

#### printtest.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

import importme

def main():
    # This line prints "<class 'importme.MyClass'>"
    m = getattr(sys.modules['importme'], sys.argv[1])
    # This line prints "<MyClass {'text':, 'number':0}>"
    #m = importme.MyClass()
    print(m)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### importme.py

```
class MyClass(object):
    text = ''
    number = 0

    def __init__(self, text = '', number = 0):
        self.text = text
        self.number = number

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<MyClass {'text':%s, 'number':%d}>" % (self.text, self.number)
```

Comment: `getattr(a, 'b')` is equivalent to `a.b`, not to `a.b()`.

Comment: is there an equivalent to `a.b()`?

Comment: `a.b()` is just "evaluate `a.b`, then call the result", so... `getattr(a, 'b')()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you fetch the *class object* of `importme.MyClass`, and the string you print is its `repr`, i.e. the `repr` of the *class object*.

In the second case, you create an instance of type `MyClass`, in which case, printing invokes your custom `repr` (`__repr__` applies to the *instance* of the class).

By the way, since you first `import importme`, this

```
getattr(sys.modules['importme'], sys.argv[1])
```

is equivalent to this:

```
getattr(importme, sys.argv[1])
```

I'm guessing what you meant to do in the first case is this:

```
m = getattr(importme, sys.argv[1])()
```